# Identifying row numbers where value is stable before and after the value in the column hits a specified value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, periodicity

### EDITED

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
data = {'ID': ['A', 'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'A',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B',    'B'],
    'column_1': [0, 0,  0,  0,  0.1,    1,  1.5,    2,  3,  4,  4.5,    5,  4.9,    3,  2,  1.8,    1,  0,  0,  1,  3,  0,  1.3,    2,  3,  4.3,    4.8,    5,  4.2,    3.5,    3,  2.6,    2,  1.9,    1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0.1,    0.2,    0.3,    1,  2,  3,  5,  4,  2,  0.5,    0,  0],
    'column_2': [13,    25, 96, 59, 5,  92, 82, 141,    50, 85, 84, 113,    119,    128,    8,  133,    82, 10, 15, 62, 11, 68, 18, 24, 37, 55, 83, 48, 13, 81, 43, 36, 56, 43, 36, 46, 45, 127,    55, 67, 113,    98, 78, 78, 57, 131,    121,    126,    142,    51, 64, 95]}


    ID  column_1  column_2
0   A       0.0        13
1   A       0.0        25
2   A       0.0        96
3   A       0.0        59
4   A       0.1         5
5   A       1.0        92
6   A       1.5        82
7   A       2.0       141
8   A       3.0        50
9   A       4.0        85
10  A       4.5        84
11  A       5.0       113
12  A       4.9       119
13  A       3.0       128
14  A       2.0         8
15  A       1.8       133
16  A       1.0        82
17  A       0.0        10
18  A       0.0        15
19  A       1.0        62
20  A       3.0        11
21  A       0.0        68
22  A       1.3        18
23  A       2.0        24
24  A       3.0        37
25  A       4.3        55
26  A       4.8        83
27  A       5.0        48
28  A       4.2        13
29  A       3.5        81
30  A       3.0        43
31  A       2.6        36
32  A       2.0        56
33  A       1.9        43
34  A       1.0        36
35  A       0.0        46
36  A       0.0        45
37  A       0.0       127
38  A       0.0        55
39  A       0.0        67
40  A       0.1       113
41  A       0.2        98
42  B       0.3        78
43  B       1.0        78
44  B       2.0        57
45  B       3.0       131
46  B       5.0       121
47  B       4.0       126
48  B       2.0       142
49  B       0.5        51
50  B       0.0        64
51  B       0.0        95
```

Tracing back from when the value hits `5` in `column_1`, I want to find the value in `column_2` just before the value in `column_1` increased from `0` and just after it came back down to `0`. So, in the data frame above, the values in `column_2` would be `5`, `10` and `18`, `46`.
I want to perform some arithmetic and would like to add 2 columns `before` & `after` with those values grouped by the `ID` column.
The expected output would be:

```
    ID  column_1  column_2  Before  After
0   A       0.0        13       0      0
1   A       0.0        25       0      0
2   A       0.0        96       0      0
3   A       0.0        59       0      0
4   A       0.1         5       0      0
5   A       1.0        92       0      0
6   A       1.5        82       0      0
7   A       2.0       141       0      0
8   A       3.0        50       0      0
9   A       4.0        85       0      0
10  A       4.5        84       0      0
11  A       5.0       113       5     10
12  A       4.9       119       0      0
13  A       3.0       128       0      0
14  A       2.0         8       0      0
15  A       1.8       133       0      0
16  A       1.0        82       0      0
17  A       0.0        10       0      0
18  A       0.0        15       0      0
19  A       1.0        62       0      0
20  A       3.0        11       0      0
21  A       0.0        68       0      0
22  A       1.3        18       0      0
23  A       2.0        24       0      0
24  A       3.0        37       0      0
25  A       4.3        55       0      0
26  A       4.8        83       0      0
27  A       5.0        48      18     46
28  A       4.2        13       0      0
29  A       3.5        81       0      0
30  A       3.0        43       0      0
31  A       2.6        36       0      0
32  A       2.0        56       0      0
33  A       1.9        43       0      0
34  A       1.0        36       0      0
35  A       0.0        46       0      0
36  A       0.0        45       0      0
37  A       0.0       127       0      0
38  A       0.0        55       0      0
39  A       0.0        67       0      0
40  A       0.1       113       0      0
41  A       0.2        98       0      0
42  B       0.3        78       0      0
43  B       1.0        78       0      0
44  B       2.0        57       0      0
45  B       3.0       131       0      0
46  B       5.0       121      78     64
47  B       4.0       126       0      0
48  B       2.0       142       0      0
49  B       0.5        51       0      0
50  B       0.0        64       0      0
51  B       0.0        95       0      0
```

For a given `ID` if `column_1` starts with a non zero value, it should give the first value of `column_2` for that group.

The rest of the rows in `Before` and `After` can be filled with `null` or zeroes.
Is there an elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `where` and `shift` you can generate series where only the endpoints of the subsequences are filled and the rest is padded with `NaN`. Combined with `ffill` (or `backfill`, respectively), `loc`ating the rows where `column_1` equals 5 gives pretty much the desired result:

```py
col1 = df.column_1
col2 = df.column_2

df.loc[col1.eq(5), "Before"] = col2.where(col1.gt(0) & col1.shift().eq(0)).ffill()
df.loc[col1.eq(5), "After"] = col2.where(col1.eq(0) & col1.shift().gt(0)).backfill()
```

##### Result:

```py
   ID  column_1  column_2  Before  After
0   A       0.0        13     NaN    NaN
1   A       0.0        25     NaN    NaN
2   A       0.0        96     NaN    NaN
3   A       0.0        59     NaN    NaN
4   A       0.1         5     NaN    NaN
5   A       1.0        92     NaN    NaN
6   A       1.5        82     NaN    NaN
7   A       2.0       141     NaN    NaN
8   A       3.0        50     NaN    NaN
9   A       4.0        85     NaN    NaN
10  A       4.5        84     NaN    NaN
11  A       5.0       113     5.0   10.0
12  A       4.9       119     NaN    NaN
13  A       3.0       128     NaN    NaN
14  A       2.0         8     NaN    NaN
15  A       1.8       133     NaN    NaN
16  A       1.0        82     NaN    NaN
17  A       0.0        10     NaN    NaN
18  A       0.0        15     NaN    NaN
19  A       1.0        62     NaN    NaN
20  A       3.0        11     NaN    NaN
21  A       0.0        68     NaN    NaN
22  A       1.3        18     NaN    NaN
23  A       2.0        24     NaN    NaN
24  A       3.0        37     NaN    NaN
25  A       4.3        55     NaN    NaN
26  A       4.8        83     NaN    NaN
27  A       5.0        48    18.0   46.0
28  A       4.2        13     NaN    NaN
29  A       3.5        81     NaN    NaN
30  A       3.0        43     NaN    NaN
31  A       2.6        36     NaN    NaN
32  A       2.0        56     NaN    NaN
33  A       1.9        43     NaN    NaN
34  A       1.0        36     NaN    NaN
35  A       0.0        46     NaN    NaN
36  A       0.0        45     NaN    NaN
37  A       0.0       127     NaN    NaN
38  A       0.0        55     NaN    NaN
39  A       0.0        67     NaN    NaN
```

##### With groupby()

```py
def set_flags(frame):

    col1 = frame.column_1
    col2 = frame.column_2
    m = col1.eq(5)

    frame.loc[m, "Before"] = col2.where(col1.gt(0) & col1.shift(fill_value=0).eq(0)).ffill()
    frame.loc[m, "After"] = col2.where(col1.eq(0) & col1.shift().gt(0)).backfill()

    return frame

df[["Before", "After"]] = 0  # initializing columns with 0 keeps the int type
df = df.groupby("ID").apply(set_flags)
```

##### Result with new data

```py
   ID  column_1  column_2  Before  After
0   A       0.0        13       0      0
1   A       0.0        25       0      0
2   A       0.0        96       0      0
3   A       0.0        59       0      0
4   A       0.1         5       0      0
5   A       1.0        92       0      0
6   A       1.5        82       0      0
7   A       2.0       141       0      0
8   A       3.0        50       0      0
9   A       4.0        85       0      0
10  A       4.5        84       0      0
11  A       5.0       113       5     10
12  A       4.9       119       0      0
13  A       3.0       128       0      0
14  A       2.0         8       0      0
15  A       1.8       133       0      0
16  A       1.0        82       0      0
17  A       0.0        10       0      0
18  A       0.0        15       0      0
19  A       1.0        62       0      0
20  A       3.0        11       0      0
21  A       0.0        68       0      0
22  A       1.3        18       0      0
23  A       2.0        24       0      0
24  A       3.0        37       0      0
25  A       4.3        55       0      0
26  A       4.8        83       0      0
27  A       5.0        48      18     46
28  A       4.2        13       0      0
29  A       3.5        81       0      0
30  A       3.0        43       0      0
31  A       2.6        36       0      0
32  A       2.0        56       0      0
33  A       1.9        43       0      0
34  A       1.0        36       0      0
35  A       0.0        46       0      0
36  A       0.0        45       0      0
37  A       0.0       127       0      0
38  A       0.0        55       0      0
39  A       0.0        67       0      0
40  A       0.1       113       0      0
41  A       0.2        98       0      0
42  B       0.3        78       0      0
43  B       1.0        78       0      0
44  B       2.0        57       0      0
45  B       3.0       131       0      0
46  B       5.0       121      78     64
47  B       4.0       126       0      0
48  B       2.0       142       0      0
49  B       0.5        51       0      0
50  B       0.0        64       0      0
51  B       0.0        95       0      0
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thank You!. I need to group it by the `ID` column. Would i have to roll this method up into a function and use  `apply()`  with `groupby()`? Is there a way to do that without converting your method into a function?

Comment: Glad to help! The question is, do any of the groups start or end with non-zero values? If no, IIUC it should work without grouping because there is no risk of overlaps, but if yes, the approach needs some tweaking because it requires zeros to locate the subsequences.

Comment: Yes, between groups, there may be non zero values. Wouldnt a simple `groupby()` be applicable here?

Comment: @thentangler The approach can be wrapped in a function and applied in a `groupby`. I added a function that does that and adding `fill_value=0` to the `Before` also allows for missing leading zero-rows to be captured. It gives the expected result for your updated data. If you initialize the columns with zeros, the type doesn't change either.

Answer (score 1):

1. Identify indices where 0's and 5's are, then reset the index while preserving the original index. The original index is renamed 'index' by default.
2. We use the new index to grab the 0's right before and right after each 5.
3. After grabbing the zeros, we cross-reference back to the original index (modifying by +1 for before) to grab the relevant column_2 values.

```
zeros_fives = df.loc[df['column_1'].isin([0, 5])].reset_index()

zero_before_five = zeros_fives.loc[zeros_fives['column_1'] == 5].index - 1
zero_after_five = zeros_fives.loc[zeros_fives['column_1'] == 5].index + 1

before = zeros_fives.loc[zero_before_five, 'index'] + 1
after = zeros_fives.loc[zero_after_five, 'index']

df.loc[df['column_1'] == 5, 'before'] = df.loc[before, 'column_2'].values
df.loc[df['column_1'] == 5, 'after'] = df.loc[after, 'column_2'].values
df.fillna(0, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Thank You! How would I apply this method grouping by the `ID` column?

Comment: If all your IDs are together and there is always a 0 before and after a 5, I think it'll work as-is.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldnt always be the case :(. If the ending of the first group `A` ends with a non zero value and the beginning of the second group `B` starts with a non-zero that goes up to `5` then it would pick the value in `column_2` that corresponds with group `A'`

Comment: What would be your expected output if there is no preceding 0?

Comment: I have updated my post to include a second ID and its corresponding output. I see the issue you are trying to raise. If there is a non zero value in the beginning of a group, we can return the first value in `column_2` for that group.